# Synapse Spark Pool - limit Quota

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, quota

How can I increase the quota to create a large spark pool in synaps, in the quota section it cannot clearly identify the service

[image]

They already increased my regional vcpus quota but I continue but I can't run a large spark pool

Answer (score 0):

you might be running into this error: **MAXIMUM_WORKSPACE_CAPACITY_EXCEEDED**
there is another quota that control how many  cores you can use at the workspace level this is independant of the cores within a region.

this article walks through the process to request a higher limit or you can deploy a smaller spark pool.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-concepts#workspace-level

it could be you are running into the **AVAILABLE_COMPUTE_CAPACITY_EXCEEDED** error. this indicates that while there may be enough vcores in the region and at the workspace level. The cluster doesn't have any more available to run another process. check to make sure that you are not running multiple notebooks at the same time and that you don't have multiple spark applications running... both of these scenarios could trigger this error.

hope this helps

take a look at this article for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-concepts